# me podrian explicar como funciona este codigo en Python , sobre M.C.D?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def mcd(a, b):

C = 0

    while(b > 0):
        C = b
        b = a % b
        a = C
    return a
num1 = int(input("Introduce el primer numero: "))

num2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo numero: "))

print("EL M.C.D DE ", num1," y ", num2," ES ", mcd(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Hola Oscar21, esta pregunta tiene algunos problemas de formato y contenido. Deberías editarla para aclarar qué parte es la que no entiendes o con qué estás teniendo problemas (si el código es correcto, deberías indicar cómo lo obtuviste y quizás no sea un problema de programación sino de matemáticas). Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser bien recibidas por la comunidad. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que tienes es una implementación del algoritmo de Euclides, el cual se basa en el hecho de que al dividir a entre b (números enteros), se obtiene un cociente q y un residuo r. Es posible demostrar que el máximo común divisor de a y b es el mismo que el de b y r.

Más información puedes ver en: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Euclides

Entonces matemáticamente lo que haces es una cadena mcd(a,b) = mcd(b,r) = ... = mcd(f,0) y se usa el hecho que el mcd(a,0) siempre es a.

Ahora haciendo una prueba de escritorio a tu algoritmo, si haces mcd(12,8), como 8>0 se entra al while y C=8, b=4,a=8.

Ahora b=4>0 se entra de nuevo al while y C=4, b=0,a=4.

En este punto b=0 ya no entra al while por lo que el algoritmo regresa 4 que es la respuesta.